# Как освободить память, выделенную с помощью kCFAllocatorDefault?

Tags: xcode, macos, утечка-памяти, c++

Уважаемые форумчане!

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться. В библиотеке CoreFoundation многие функции, создающие объекты, требуют ввести параметр **CFAllocatorRef allocator**. Обычно я использую аллокатор по умолчанию, но спустя время я заметила, что память, выделенная с помощью данного аллокатора, не высвобождается с помощью `CFRelease()`. То есть после вызова `CFRelease()` к какому-либо объекту, созданному с помощью аллокатора, в среде разработки с левой стороны, где показана занимаемая программой память, она не уменьшается, и таким образом происходят утечки. Как с этим бороться? Как гарантированно освободить память, выделенную под эти объекты?

Пример кода (здесь я уже пробую kCFAllocatorMalloc, но память так и не вернулась):

```
CFHTTPMessageRef myRequest = CFHTTPMessageCreateRequest(kCFAllocatorMalloc,
                                                        requestMethod,
                                                        myUrl,
                                                        kCFHTTPVersion1_1);
CFRelease(myRequest); //память после этого не освободилась
myRequest = NULL;
```

Читала ссылки с документацией, особо не помогло:

[Allocators](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Allocators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001146-CJBEJBHH)

[Creating Custom Allocators](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Tasks/CustomAllocators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001154-CJBEHAAG)

[CFAllocator Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFAllocatorRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFAllocatorDeallocate)

[Ownership Policy](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001148-103029)

[Что нужно знать об ARC](http://habrahabr.ru/post/209288/)